# how to unzip more than one zip file and delete it

Tags: vb.net, unzip

When i am geting more than one zip file i can't unzip the second zip file
For example there is a .tif inside the zip file, when its loopign the unzip funcion its say the .tif is already exists.

```
Try
    If Not Directory.Exists(extractPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath)
    End If

    Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)
        For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), extractPath)
        Next
    End Using

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(dl.getconnstr)
        cn.Open()
        Using tran As SqlTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("", cn, tran)

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tableXXX SET unziped='Y' WHERE attachfile='" + zipPath + "'"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(dl.getconnstr)
        cn.Open()
        Using tran As SqlTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("", cn, tran)

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tableXXX SET unziped='N' WHERE attachfile='" + zipPath + "'"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't really make sense. If you're going to do this:

```vb
For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
```

then you're supposed to use `entry` inside the loop to extract that one entry. `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` extracts all entries in an archive to a directory, so it should be obvious that you would only call that once per archive. What you are doing is extracting every entry once for every entry that is in the archive, e.g. if there are 10 entries then you extract all 10 entries 10 times. Obviously that makes no sense and that's why you are being told something already exists on the second iteration: because you just created it on the previous iteration.

You need to decide whether you want to use a loop or `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` and do just that. You don't use both.